# Redirecting after task w/ Await completes

Tags: swift, swiftui

In a view, I want to wait for a series of async calls to finish loading, then redirect to another screen. Unfortunately, I see the code running in the back (The JSON data gets loaded) but once it completes it does not redirect to the new view.

Here is my view:

```
struct loadingView: View {
    @ObservedObject var dataLoader: DataLoader = DataLoader()
    @State var isLoaded: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
           Text("Loading \(isLoaded)")
        }
    }
    .task {
        await self.dataloader.loadJSONData(isLoaded: $isLoaded)
        MainScreen()
    }
}
```

...and the DataLoader class:

```
@MainActor DataLoader: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    func loadJSONData(isLoaded: Binding<Bool>) {
        await doLoadData()
        isLoaded.wrappedValue = True
    }

    func doLoadData() async {
        /* do data load */
        /* This code works */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Redirecting" here doesn't really make sense. Do you really want the user to be able to navigate back to the loading screen? Perhaps you're thinking of this like a web page, but SwiftUI is nothing like that. What you really want to do is display one thing when loading, and a different thing when loaded. That's just `if`, not "redirection."

Instead, consider the following pattern. Create this kind of LoadingView (extracted from some personal code of mine):

```
struct LoadingView<Content: View, Model>: View {
    enum LoadState {
        case loading
        case loaded(Model)
        case error(Error)
    }

    @ViewBuilder let content: (Model) -> Content
    let loader: () async throws -> Model

    @State var loadState = LoadState.loading

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.white
            switch loadState {
            case .loading: Text("Loading")
            case .loaded(let model): content(model)
            case .error(let error): Text(verbatim: "Error: \(error)")
            }
        }
        .task {
            do {
                loadState = .loaded(try await loader())
            } catch {
                loadState = .error(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It require no redirection. It just displays different things when in different states (obviously the `Text` view can be replaced by something more interesting).

Then to use this, embed it in another View. In my personal code, that includes a view like this:

```
struct DailyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        LoadingView() { model in
            LoadedDailyView(model: model)
        } loader: {
            try await DailyModel()
        }
    }
}
```

Then LoadedDailyView is the "real" view. It is handled a fully populated `model` that is created by `DailyModel.init` (a throwing, async init).

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach, using `NavigationStack` and `NavigationPath` to `Redirecting after task w/ Await completes`.

Here is the code I use to test my answer:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        loadingView()
    }
}

@MainActor
class DataLoader: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    func loadJSONData() async {
        await doLoadData()
        // for testing, wait for 1 second
        try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1 * 1_000_000_000)
    }

    func doLoadData() async {
        /* do data load */
        /* This code works */
    }
}

struct loadingView: View {
    @StateObject var dataLoader = DataLoader()
    @State private var navPath = NavigationPath()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $navPath) {
            VStack (spacing: 44) {
                Text("Loading....")
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Bool.self) { _ in
                MainScreen()
            }
        }
        .task {
            await dataLoader.loadJSONData()
            navPath.append(true)
        }
    }
}

struct MainScreen: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("---> MainScreen here <---")
    }
}
```

If you need ios 15 or earlier, then use `NavigationView`:

```
struct loadingView: View {
    @StateObject var dataLoader = DataLoader()
    @State var isLoaded: Bool?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text(isLoaded == nil ? "Loading..." : "Finished loading")
                NavigationLink("", destination: MainScreen(), tag: true, selection: $isLoaded)
            }
        }.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
        .task {
            await dataLoader.loadJSONData()
            isLoaded = true
        }
    }
}
```

If your `loadingView` has the only purpose of showing the "loading" message, then
display the `MainScreen` after the data is loaded, you could use the following approach using a simple swicth:

```
struct loadingView: View {
    @StateObject var dataLoader = DataLoader()
    @State private var isLoaded = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if isLoaded {
                MainScreen()
            } else {
                ProgressView("Loading")
            }
        }
        .task {
            await dataLoader.loadJSONData()
            isLoaded = true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@StateObject` instead of `@ObservedObject`. Use `@Published` instead of trying to pass a binding to the object (that is a mistake because a binding is just a pair of get and set closures that will expire if `LoadingView` is re-init), use `Group` with an `if` to conditionally show a `View` e.g.

```
struct LoadingView: View {
    @StateObject var dataLoader: DataLoader = DataLoader()

    var body: some View {
        Group {
           if dataLoader.isLoaded {
               LoadedView(data: dataLoader.data)
           } else {
                Text("Loading...")
           }
        }
        .task {
            await dataloader.loadJSONData()
        }
    }
```

The `DataLoader` should not be `@MainActor` because you want it to run on a background thread. Use `@MainActor` instead on a sub-task once the async work has finished e.g.

```
class DataLoader: ObservableObject {

    @Published var isLoaded = false
    @Published var data: [Data] = []

    func loadJSONData async {
        let d = await doLoadData()
        Task { @MainActor in
            isLoaded = true
            data = d
        }
    }

    func doLoadData() async {
        /* do data load */
        /* This code works */
    }
}
```

This pattern is shown in Apple's tutorial [here](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/sample-apps/memecreator#Fetching-Panda-Data), `PandaCollectionFetcher.swift` copied below:

```
import SwiftUI

class PandaCollectionFetcher: ObservableObject {
    @Published var imageData = PandaCollection(sample: [Panda.defaultPanda])
    @Published var currentPanda = Panda.defaultPanda
    
    let urlString = "http://playgrounds-cdn.apple.com/assets/pandaData.json"
    
    enum FetchError: Error {
        case badRequest
        case badJSON
    }
    
     func fetchData() async 
     throws  {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }

        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: URLRequest(url: url))
        guard (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 200 else { throw FetchError.badRequest }

        Task { @MainActor in
            imageData = try JSONDecoder().decode(PandaCollection.self, from: data)
        }
    }
    
}
```